# WoeUSB error while creating windows 7 bootable usb

Tags: grub2, windows-7, woeusb

Everything goes fine, but in the end I get this error every time one the GUI install as well as in terminal:

```
Mounting target filesystem...
Applying workaround to prevent 64-bit systems with big primary memory from being unresponsive during copying files.
Copying files from source media...
Installing GRUB bootloader for legacy PC booting support...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installing custom GRUB config for legacy PC booting...
Resetting workaround to prevent 64-bit systems with big primary memory from being unresponsive during copying files.
/usr/bin/woeusb: line 1676: echo: write error: Invalid argument
The command "exit 0" failed with exit status "1", program is prematurely aborted
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: What are you formatting the USB to?  Maybe try formatting it to NTFS first.  An idea from another woeusb question.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the error, USB should still boot fine.

https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/issues/275

> It turns out the USB drive was successfully written. Only some cleanup process crashed causing further writes on the same session to crash as well.

However I would say WoeUSB is now obsolete. I would recommend Ubuntu's mkusb tool:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

This will author Windows & Linux USB drives. (However if you have a PC that'll only boot a Windows authored drive, that drive has to be 8GB or larger. You may need to author a Linux image the Windows way for instance, eg: Clonezilla is not 8GB, the pen drive still needs to be 8GB or larger or script will not execute.)